# Error: Cannot find module '/Users/dir1/dir2/script1.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am coming across the below error when I try running the node js script I have written

```
$ node script1.js
module.js:338   
throw err;
        ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/dir1/dir2/script1.js'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
  at startup (node.js:124:16) 
  at node.js:811:3
```

Is there something I am missing on including?

Comment: Can we see the code you wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured that it is a bad character issue in the case of this script.
Re-typing the script helped resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting indicates that your `script1.js` file is not where you think it is. Here's an example of what happens if I run Node on a non-existent file:

```
$ node non-existent

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/non-existent'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Find out where your file is and provide node with the right path.